# Proper vspacing after itemize in minipage

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, minipage

## My situation

I have an environment that consists of an `itemize` set withing a `minipage` (or `varwidth`, whatever...)

Let's call this environment `myItemize`.

I am encountering difficulty regarding the vertical spacing after and `\end{myItemize}`

(I do not care about the vertical spacing before the `\begin{`)

All code is at the end.

### regular spacing after `myItemize` : ok-ish

By fiddling in `myItemize` definition, I can just about have it behave when followed by *"regular text"*.

#### Illustration :

[image]

### spacing before `\item` after `myItemize` : not ok

If the `myItemize` is nested inside an `itemize`, the *ad-hoc* spacing is no longer relevant.

Can someone show me the magic to be cast to have the same spacing after `myItemize` as would be after a `itemize` in both cases ?

I tried a bit with `\ignorespacesafterend` but no luck !

#### Illustration :

[image]

## The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{myItemize}
{%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
}
{%
    \end{itemize}
    \strut
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{-2.3\baselineskip}
  \vspace{-\lineskip}

  \strut
}
\newcommand\myCommand[2]
{
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{#1}
    \item this is #2
    \item spacing below is about \textsc{ok}
  \end{#1}

  dummy below

  \hrulefill
\end{minipage}
}

\myCommand{myItemize}{{\verb!myItemize}}%
\myCommand{itemize}{{\verb!itemize}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item dummy item
    \begin{itemize}
      \item this is \verb!itemize!
      \item spacing is \textsc{ok}
    \end{itemize}
  \item dummy item

    \begin{myItemize}
      \item this is \verb!myItemize!
      \item spacing below is not \textsc{ok}
      \item I don't care about above spacing
    \end{myItemize}

  \item dummy item
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Just an idea: Do not use `itemize` in your minipage directly, but use an own list defined by enumitem and adjust skips via its setup options.

Comment: @TeXnician In my documents, I actually do use `enumitem`, but took this off for minimalism. What kind of *list* do you mean ? A regular `list` environment ? I don't think I know much about these, of have much documentation at my disposal, either...

Comment: Have a look at the enumitem documentation p. 10 (about `\newlist`). If you have such a new list you can configure it the enumitem way (including settings per nesting level).

Comment: The `minipage` environment changes explicitly the inter-item spacings. I've answered this some while ago... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257836/31729

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is not about the spacing **between** items, it is about the spacing **after** the environment.

Comment: It should be noted that \endtrivlist (which is used by all lists) does different things based on a number of flags, like \if@inlabel, \if@newlist, \ifhmode and \if@noparlist.  If I knew what all of these meant, it might explain some of the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is the use of `\begin` inside an environment.  Your original code would have expanded as:

```
\begin{MyItemize}
\begin{minipage}
\begin{itemize}
\end{MyItemize}
\end(itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

which is out of order.  (`\end` tests `\@currenvir` against `#1`)

Second, `\item` adds `\itemsep`, except when in vmode.  So part of the problem is how to avoid being in vmode without adding an extra line.  In any case, the solution was to add a `\strut` to the last `\item` rather than to the end of itemize.

Third, itemize ends with a skip but minipage doesn't.  The only way I could find to fix the `\myCommand` alignment without adding a line was to use `\unskip` in `\myCommand`, then put the skip back in.  (Actually, the skip removed was `13.0pt plus 6.0pt minus 8.0pt` whereas `\baselineskip=14.5pt`.  I haven't managed to identify the name of the skip used by itemize.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{myItemize}
{%
  \noindent
  \minipage{\linewidth}\null
    \itemize
}
{%
    \strut\enditemize
  \endminipage
}

\newcommand\myCommand[2]
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}\null
  \begin{#1}
    \item this is #2
    \item spacing below is about \textsc{ok}
  \end{#1}\unskip\par\vskip\baselineskip

  dummy below \the\parskip

  \hrulefill
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
\myCommand{myItemize}{myItemize}%
\myCommand{itemize}{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
  \item dummy item
    \begin{itemize}
      \item this is \verb!itemize!
      \item spacing is \textsc{ok}
    \end{itemize}
  \item dummy item \smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep}}

    \begin{myItemize}
      \item this is \verb!myItemize!
      \item spacing below is not \textsc{ok}
      \item I don't care about above spacing
    \end{myItemize}

  \item dummy item \smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I hadn't understood the point you raise on environments in `\newenvironment`. Unfortunately, your answer solves only one half of the issue. Please see my answer for clarification.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was getting errors from the \myCommand code so simply deleted them.

Comment: I think the skip you could not identify is `\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep`. Thanks for the good work, I learnt good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I explained myself poorly in the question.

John's solution is ok if the environment is followed by an `\item`, but not for regular text, but I would like the *"after"* `vspace` to be correct regardless.

I build from [this solution by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179034/116936), to get rid conditionally of the extra `\baselineskip` introduced by `\item`.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\detectItem{%
  \@ifnextchar\item%
    {\par\kern-\baselineskip}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\def\useDetectItem#1\ignorespaces\fi{#1\fi\detectItem}

\newenvironment{myItemize}
{%
  \noindent
  \minipage{\linewidth}
    \itemize
}
{%
    \strut%\smash{\rule[\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\itemsep]{1pt}{1cm}}
    \enditemize
  \endminipage%
  \par\kern\dimexpr\baselineskip-.7\lineskip\relax
  \aftergroup\useDetectItem}

\newcommand\myCommand[2]
{%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{#1}
    \item this is {\verb!#2}
    \item spacing below is \textsc{ok}
  \end{#1}
  dummy below

  \hrulefill
\end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{390pt}
\myCommand{myItemize}{myItemize}%
\myCommand{itemize}{itemize}


\begin{itemize}
  \item dummy item
    \begin{itemize}
      \item this is \verb!itemize!
      \item spacing is \textsc{ok}
    \end{itemize}
  \item dummy item \smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep}}

    \begin{myItemize}
      \item this is \verb!myItemize!
      \item spacing below is now \textsc{ok}
      \item I don't care about above spacing
    \end{myItemize}
  \item dummy item \smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep}}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```