# Different spacing for same enumerate!

Tags: spacing, enumerate, minipage

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, top=.25in, bottom=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{%
  fontspec,
  parskip,
  lastpage,
  booktabs,
  polyglossia,
  graphicx, 
  fancyhdr,
  lato
}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Lato}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.15in}
\setlength{\headsep}{.15in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\lhead{\footnotesize{Hello\\Hello }}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{
      \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is 1
          \item This is 2
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{minipage}
    }
  \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is 1
      \item This is 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

The spacing between items in the minipage and outside the minipage is different!

How do I get the spacing to be uniform?

Comment: The spacing for list - like environments is different within `minipage` and outside of it. And `enumerate` and `enumitem` packages together is not a healthy combination

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257809/list-spacing-is-different-inside-and-outside-of-minipage

Answer (score 1):

I would use tcolorbox to create the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners]
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is 1
          \item This is 2
        \end{enumerate}      
\end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is 1
      \item This is 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using the tcolorbox part in the MWE I have provided. It still produces different spacing of items in and out the box. Will you please try to use my MWE to see if it creates the same problem at your end, too?