# Problem of horizontal alignment for list items in a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, minipage

To be able to put a figure on the right side of the text in a list item, I use the `minipage` environment (see code below; in practice, the `minipage` will be narrower than `\linewidth`). For some reason, line "|Y y|" is not aligned with lines "|W w|" and "|Z z|" on the left, although lines "|V v|" and "|X x|" are properly aligned. Where does it come from and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  $|$V\hfill v$|$
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    $|$W\hfill w$|$
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    $|$X\hfill x$|$
    \begin{enumerate}
      \addtocounter{enumii}{1}%
    \item
      $|$Y\hfill y$|$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \addtocounter{enumii}{2}%
  \item
    $|$Z\hfill z$|$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257809/list-spacing-is-different-inside-and-outside-of-minipage

The reason is, that within a `minipage`, the listing level is reset. Thus, „|Y y|“ uses the spacing of a first level entry. You can use `\parbox` instead of `minipage`, which does not behave this way. You can also set the listing level within the `minipage` explicitly with `\@mplistdepth=1`.

Comment: It works! If you convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it. Although it is indeed a duplicate, it might be worth to keep my question (and your answer) since I did not find the other question, despite some search. I thought that it might be a matter of list depth, but since I use `enumerate`, I just checked `\@enumdepth`, and this one was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate: A similar problem has already been discussed before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257809/list-spacing-is-different-inside-and-outside-of-minipage).

The reason is that within a `minipage`, the listing level is reset. Thus, “|Y y|” uses the spacing of a first level entry, which is obviously not what you want. You can use a `\parbox` instead of `minipage`, which does not behave this way. You can also set the listing level within the minipage explicitly with `\@mplistdepth=1`. Please see the above link for other solutions that may better suit your case.